# How to conditionally add value converters if database is SQLite

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a question that might be dumb but I've only just discovered Data Conversion in EF Core.

So I need to use a value converter only if the database in use is an SQLite database. Is this possible?

Again; sorry if this question is kinda dumb. Thanks!

Comment: Try `if (Database.IsSqlite()) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SqliteDatabaseFacadeExtensions` Class, There is a static method:

```
public static bool IsSqlite (this Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade database);
```

It Returns `true` if the database provider currently in use is the SQLite provider.

You can use `YourDatabase.IsSqlite()` to determine if the database you are using is Sqlite.

You can refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlitedatabasefacadeextensions.issqlite?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlitedatabasefacadeextensions-issqlite(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-infrastructure-databasefacade)) to learn more.